# Make third column of dataframe equal one if two other columns both equal one

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm relatively new to R, and I'm playing around with it to get better. simple question:

I have two columns with true/false represented as 1/0 respectively
I want to make a third column that has true/false, again represented as 1/0, being true if both of the first two columns are true

so with this example dataset, if a and b BOTH equal 1, how would I get column c to have a value of 1 as well?

```
a   b   c
1   1   1
1   0   0
0   1   0
```

Comment: `dat$c <- as.integer(dat$a == 1 & dat$b == 1)`

Comment: Assuming your data frame is called `dat`.

Comment: or `dat$c <- ifelse(dat$a == 1 && dat$b == 1,  0)`

Comment: `transform(DF, c = a * b)`